# Theoretical functional dependency

Tags: functional-dependencies

I'm learning about functional dependencies and i got stuck on this:

> Given the table L(A,B,C,D)  and FD's: AB->C, C->D
>
> Can we get functional dependency BC->D from it? why?

I would say yes, because we have C->D, and we could just go BC->DB, and then split it into BC->D and BC->B. Is this line of reasoning correct?

> Is table L in 2nd Normal Form? Is it in 3rd? Is it in 3.5 Normal form?

Now this, im not sure: I think its in second, but not third normal form, but i have no idea if its in 3.5 (maybe yes, because we only have one key (AB)?) 
If its not, how would we go around making it into 3.5NF ?

Comment: If you want to know what NFs a table is in then you must find the *defintions* of these NFs. And you put a table into a NF by finding then following an *algorithmn* designed for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `AB → C, C → D` you can derive `BC → D`, and your reasoning is correct. This can be shown by using the [Armstrong’s axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms):

```
1. From C → D you can derive BC → BD (by augmentation with B)
2. From BC → BD you can derive BC → D (by decomposition)
```

Since the only candidate key of the relation is AB (so AB are prime attributes), the dependency C → D violates both the Third Normal Form as well as the Boyce-Codd Normal Form (sometimes called the 3.5 normal form). A relation is in BCNF if every determinant is a superkey, and this is not the case since `C` is not a superkey. A relation could be in 3NF if, even the determinant is not a superkey, the determinate is a prime attribute (and this is not the case since `D` is not prime). The schema is instead in 2NF, because there are no non-prime attributes that depend on a proper subset of a candidate key.